# Tensorflow: Using Parameter Servers in Distributed Training

Tags: python, tensorflow

It's not totally clear how parameter servers know what to do in a distributed tensor flow training.

For example, in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37712509/how-to-run-tensorflow-distributed-mnist-example), the following code is used to configure parameter server and worker tasks:

```
if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
    server.join()
elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":
    ##some training code
```

How does `server.join()` indicate the given task should be a parameter server? Is parameter serving a kind of default behavior for tasks? Is there anything else you can/should tell a parameter serving task to do?

**Edit**: This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185702/distributed-tensorflow-parameter-server-and-workers) addresses some of my question: "The logic there makes sure that Variable objects are assigned evenly to workers that act as parameter servers." But how does a parameter server know it is a parameter server? Is `server.join()` enough?

Comment: "parameter server" is the thing that holds variables. This is legacy naming inherited from the time when Google needed to separate binaries for jobs that storing the variable. In tensorflow this is extraneous distinction since worker can also store variables. Here's example of two workers launched identically where the first one acts as parameter server -- https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/1124bb02a9fd4abce3d86caf2f950cb2

Comment: This is helpful. From what I understand it can be more efficient to have a centralized store for values (parameter server) that all workers can communicate with, rather than each worker having to communicate with all others. Does tensorflow automatically adopt this communication configuration?

Comment: not really -- if you use with tf.device(tf.replica_device_setter...) it puts variables created in that block on a set of "ps" workers, so those workers act as a distributed parameter server. If you don't use this construct, you could have a graph where every worker talks to every worker

Comment: So what is the "best" practice to achieve distributed tensorflow? Use with tf.device(tf.replica_device_setter...) or don't use this construct? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**TL;DR:** TensorFlow doesn't know anything about "parameter servers", but instead it supports running graphs across multiple devices in different processes. Some of these processes have devices whose names start with `"/job:ps"`, and these hold the variables. The workers drive the training process, and when they run the `train_op` they will cause work to happen on the `"/job:ps"` devices, which will update the shared variables.

The [`server.join()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train.html#Server.join) method simply tells TensorFlow to block and listen for requests until the server shuts down (which currently means it blocks forever, or until you kill the process, since clean shutdown isn't currently implemented).

In the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37823338/3574081) in my previous answer, the PS tasks are passive, and everything is controlled by the worker tasks... in `## some training code`. If you split your code across multiple devices, TensorFlow will add the appropriate communication, and this extends to devices in different processes. The `with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(...)):` block tells TensorFlow to put each variable on a different PS task by setting its device to `"/job:ps/task:{i}"` (for different values of `{i}`, chosen in a round-robin fashion).

When you call `sess.run(train_op)`, TensorFlow will run a graph that depends on and updates the variables, and includes the operations that update them. This part of the computation will happen on the `"/job:ps"` devices, so those devices will act like a parameter server.

Comment: This is really helpful! For my own understanding, is there any way that TF controls how the tasks communicate? E.g. is there anything stopping workers from requesting and updating parameter values amongst themselves, which would defeat the purpose? This might be a bit into the weeds but any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: TF imposes very little policy on this. When you create the `tf.train.Server`, you define the cluster as a set of network addresses, and this basically sets up the mapping from device names (i.e. the `/job:{name}/task:{i}` part) to network addresses. After that, you're free to define graphs that run across any subset of the tasks. If you wanted to cache the variables on the workers, you could do that, and you could certainly add direct worker-to-worker communication if that would be useful.

Comment: So what is the "best" practice to achieve distributed tensorflow? Use with tf.device(tf.replica_device_setter...) or don't use this construct? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Comment: +++ to the previous question from @urey

Comment: @mrry  Can you please explain more about worker cause variable update on ps? I have opened another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48318936/how-tensorflow-worker-driver-training-process-and-cause-variables-update-on-ps-j