# how tensorflow worker driver training process and cause variables update on ps job?

Tags: tensorflow

I am reading tensorflow code, and come across this answer [tensorflow-using-parameter-servers-in-distributed-training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979688/tensorflow-using-parameter-servers-in-distributed-training)

would very much like to know the detail?

Answer (score 2):

There's some deal of detail here on how to set up and use distributed models at https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed.

It appears that there's little distinction between workers and "parameter servers" other than that the `ps` nodes have no code beyond `server.join()`, which allows other nodes to place ops on them.  In the example at the above documentation, the code run on the workers establishes variables on the `ps` devices, computes models using them, and optimizes them as if they were local resources - using essentially the same `with` mechanism as if one were to assign an op to a gpu or cpu.

Is there something more specific you're interested in knowing?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am trying to understand the tensorflow implementation, as you say "as if they were local resources ", actually they are not, so how tensorflow know they are local or remote resources, I know     it is because we set "cluster spec" in the code, but when and where this spec is actually used to distinguish if variables is stored in local or remote in its C++/python implementation?

Comment: @袁定平, It's not just "cluster spec", but if you look at "Specifying distributed devices in your model" in the above link, you can see that the ops are defined using, for example, `with tf.device("/job:ps/task:0"):  weights_1 = tf.Variable(...)`; this tells the local device to assign it to parameter server 0, which it knows through the  ClusterSpec op, whose arguments ultimately come from the command line invocation of Python in this example.  As for more detailed specifics, you might need to dig into the source code.  Cheers and looking forward to hearing about what you learn!